# Does a large XAML cause the push navigation of a xamarin forms page to slow down?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Does a large XAML cause the push navigation of a Xamarin forms page to slow down? 
Also do static resources included from app.xaml play a part? What can be done to improve the navigation speed?

Comment: Are you using the Xaml Compiler? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/ In terms of "large" XAML-based content, it is highly dependent upon the layout and content that you are displaying and how the content of the page is obtain. Without details of what you are doing, it would be a complete guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be. if its an huge issue. then

- make a pure code-behind version - 
  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48200/is-there-a-way-to-speed-up-xaml-page-loading
- Try Fast Renderers  - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/under-the-hood/fast-renderers/